# angular js dependency module config works one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a module composition like this:

```
angular.module('mainModule',["cityModule", "countryModule"]);
angular.module('mapModule',[]);
angular.module('cityModule',["mapModule"]);
angular.module('countryModule',["mapModule"]);
```

main module contains `countryModule` and `cityModule`. And `mapModule` goes to `cityModule` and `countryModule`.

so I have a config on mapModule.

```
angular.module("mapModule").config([function () {
      console.log("this is map config")
}]);
```

I have seen that writes **"this is map config"** only one time. But I referenced mapModule two different modules (cityModule and countryModule).
Should it write two times? Why?

(if I have a provider on mapModule it writes console one times as well.)

Answer (score 0):

The single output is correct.

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> Modules can list other modules as their dependencies. Depending on a
>   module implies that the required module needs to be loaded before the
>   requiring module is loaded. In other words the configuration blocks of
>   the required modules execute before the configuration blocks of the
>   requiring module. The same is true for the run blocks. **Each module can
>   only be loaded once, even if multiple other modules require it.**

In your example mapModule's config will run first, but only once.